# How to Iterate over an Object inside an Object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an Object which further contains an Object inside. How can I get values of the inside Object. I don't care too much about the keys but it will be nice if I can get that as well.

The response looks like this:

```
res = {data: {name: 'name', id: 1, city: 'LA'}}
```

I want to do this in typescript.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is the key always `data`?  Or do you not know the key? What is the *type* of `res` (since you are using TypeScript)?

Comment: Yes it is always data. res is of type Object

Comment: If you know it's always `data`, then `Object` is too wide of a type.  In fact it should be something more like `{data: object}` or `{data: {[k: string]: string | number}` or `{data: {name: string, id: number, city: string}}` or something.  Please post a [mre] suitable for pasting into a standalone IDE so we can advise further.

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate on the object data inside object res using for loop

```
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(res.data)) {
      console.log(key, value);
}
```

you will get the key and value

```
name    name
​id      1
​city    LA
```

Comment: res.data is giving me error

Comment: @Cpt.Kitkat you can update code get api ? I see his code very okie.